# Laravel POST request on cpanel gets 405 error back sometimes

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-405

So, this is my first post on stack overflow, if I missed something please let me know.

So I have some sort of a weird problem that I can't figure out.
I have a laravel 8 application, worked on it on my machine and things seemed ok, after uploading it on a cpanel I got stuck with this weird problem.

I have a form:

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.store') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

The form has some inputs, a textarea and a file input.
Those are my routes:

```
Route::prefix('articles')->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'create'])->name('articles.create');
    Route::post('/store', [\App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'store'])->name('articles.store');
});
```

When I submit the form I get the *The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.* error.

I opened the Network console in chrome, checked the preserve logs checkbox and did the request again and in the list it looks like this did the POST request, but received a 405

[image: A picture of the call in the network tab of chrome inspector]

I checked in my cpanel *Select PHP Version* page the **post_max_size** and **upload_max_size** options and they are at **1G**.

Also, tried to change the route to PUT and use @method('PUT') but I got the same result.

Also, a weird part is that if I submit the form with no content it works, I get the validations back as intended, but as soon as I fill even one of the fields I get the method not allowed error.

Maybe you guys have any idea what is happening here and point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you test it again, just remove the middlewares ?

Comment: @justMike do you have any hidden field in the form? Could you post the all fields that are within the form? Also try to run command php artisan route:list and see if you are seeing the correct route for articles.store

Comment: I have no hidden fields in my form, only the csrf from the @csrf. Runned the route:list, this is it: |        | POST     | articles/store                   | articles.store                  | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@store         | App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies                      |

Comment: It looks like I can't post the form, becaus the content it is too large.

Comment: **405** _methodNotAllowed_ exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting. @justMike are you uning http or https?

Comment: @sta - the problem is that the route is defined in the routes/web.php file, the route:list command runned on the server shows that the route exists and it is on post method, this is working perfectly fine on the local environment, but not on the cpanel machine.

Comment: I'm using https, in my .env file I have declared the app_url like this `APP_URL=https://subdomain.domain.com`

Comment: I am also having the same problem but for the DELETE request, locally it works fine but on cPanel I get the 405 error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clear the route cache with the following command on the server and try again?

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: I runned the command several thimes but the result is the same. I also removed the middleware from the routes group, but without effect.